# How to run a query that is configured in the database column using spring boot

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am looking to achieve below functionality, 
using stack: Spring-boot, hibernate, MySQL

1) I have a table called configuration I have 2 columns id, select_clause

2) I am going to store my queries in this configuration table

Example: select select_clause from configuration where id = 999;

Output: SELECT * FROM user u where  u.CREATE_DATE > '2019-03-25'

3) I have the other table called user, from the user repository how do i run the query that is returned from the point 2), which is SELECT * FROM user u where u.CREATE_DATE > '2019-03-25'

I am trying below.

```
String query = configDTO.getSelectClause();

// query value is "SELECT * FROM user u where  u.CREATE_DATE > '2019-03-25'"

UserDTO userDTO = userRoleRepository.getReportByCustom(query);
```

My native query in the repository is

```
@Query(value = ":query",  nativeQuery=true)
public UserDTO getReportByCustom(@Param("query") String query);
```

What am i mssing?

error is 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''SELECT * FROM user u where  u.CREATE_DATE > '2019-03-25''' at line 1

Comment: String query = configDTO.getSelectClause();

// query value is "SELECT * FROM user u where  u.CREATE_DATE > '2019-03-25'"

UserDTO userDTO = userRoleRepository.getReportByCustom(query);

My native query in the repository is

@Query(value = ":query",  nativeQuery=true)
public UserDTO getReportByCustom(@Param("query") String query);

but getting error, updated the question

Comment: You can't use Spring Data repository method if you want to run a dynamic query. Dynamic query is a query that application doesn't know about when it is compiled. You'll have to use EntityManager to create query and run it. It doesn't seem like a good design, as you will have to know in advance what JPA object is going to be returned by each query.